# How to prevent WordPress from loading the jQuery library at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, templates, https

I am developing a site that must be HTTPS secure and WordPress is loading `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` at the very top of my page, before `<html>` and giving me an insecure error. I cannot find where this is being loaded from to prevent it from loading.

Unfortunately I cannot show the site as it's a federal credit union site and it would be against our contract agreement for me to present this site publicly before it is complete.

Here's a screenshot of the issue via Chrome web dev tools (click to zoom):

[image: Chrome]

Comment: it's your theme or a plugin, core WordPress and default themes don't do that.

Comment: I have deactivated all my plugins to see if that would fix it and it did not. The site is built on a custom framework and I have nothing in there that would load that library. I think it's some sort of inherited `wp_enqueue_script` issue.

Comment: not sure what you mean by inherited `wp_enqueue_script` issue. WordPress loads it's own version of jQuery from the includes folder, so your theme is doing something somewhere.

Comment: Agree with Milo. If your plugins are eliminated, it can only be your theme. try switching to a standard theme (twentysomething). Does the problem go away? Of course it does.

Comment: Do you realize the site URL is in the screenshot you added?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I build themes, I also like to make the WordPress header as clean as possible and then reconstruct it to my own liking. The code below is excessive for your question, but it might help you with other 'WordPress inserted code' in the future. The key snippet of code you are looking for is

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
wp_register_script('jquery', '', '', '', true);
```

Put this in your `functions.php` file.

My whole WordPress header cleanup:

```
/* =Clean up the WordPress head
------------------------------------------------- */

    // remove header links
    add_action('init', 'tjnz_head_cleanup');
    function tjnz_head_cleanup() {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );                      // Category Feeds
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );                            // Post and Comment Feeds
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );                                 // EditURI link
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );                         // Windows Live Writer
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' );                           // index link
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0 );              // previous link
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0 );               // start link
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );   // Links for Adjacent Posts
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );                             // WP version
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');                                     // De-Register jQuery
            wp_register_script('jquery', '', '', '', true);                     // Register as 'empty', because we manually insert our script in header.php
        }
    }

    // remove WP version from RSS
    add_filter('the_generator', 'tjnz_rss_version');
    function tjnz_rss_version() { return ''; }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marc! The `wp_deregister_script` worked perfectly. I am not using any of Wordpress' theme stuff, writing my own head, header, content, footer, etc. So I was confused why it was loading that jQuery library.

Comment: @AnthoneyCarter once again, if it's sourced from `code.jquery.com` **it's not WordPress that's responsible**. this is simply deregistering jquery which was registered elsewhere by the theme or a plugin. furthermore, you *will* break things if you use a plugin that requires jQuery. doing this is not recommended, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the library from jQuery.com and load it as a normal script in your functions.php file and end `wp_enqueue_script` in a `true` statement, this prints the script just before the `</body>`.

```php
wp_enqueue_script('customjquery', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '2.1.4', true);
```

WordPress still uses jQuery 1.something I believe. I pull jQuery separate because I'm using the latest version of bootstrap and want the lastest version of jQuery. Just remember to add true to your statement